# Генерация всех перестановок чисел в едином SQL Запросе

Tags: sql, oracle

Генерируем последовательность

```
with t as (select level n 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 8)
  ...
```

И вот с ней нужно придумать что можно сделать чтобы получить все комбинации от 1 до 8. Я пока нашел только такой способ:

```
with nums as (select level as nv from dual connect by level <= 8)
select n1.nv A,n2.nv B, n3.nv C, n4.nv D, n5.nv E, n6.nv F, n7.nv G, n8.nv H
  from nums n1
    cross join nums n2
    cross join nums n3
    cross join nums n4
    cross join nums n5
    cross join nums n6
    cross join nums n7
    cross join nums n8
where POWER(2, n1.nv) + 
      POWER(2, n2.nv) + 
      POWER(2, n3.nv) + 
      POWER(2, n4.nv) + 
      POWER(2, n5.nv) + 
      POWER(2, n6.nv) + 
      POWER(2, n7.nv) +
      POWER(2, n8.nv) = 510;
```

Но он долгий в силу необходимости возводить в степень (у меня 25 секунд отрабатывал). Есть ли более элегантный способ? Например, в моем больном сознании родилось нечто вроде:

```
SELECT str FROM (
  with t as (select to_char(level) as ch from dual connect by level <= 8)
  SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ch, '.') as str
    FROM t CONNECT BY level <= 8 and INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ch, '.'),ch,1,1) = 0
)
  WHERE INSTR(str,'.',1,8)>0
```

Но SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH после where недопустима, как и str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так можно сгенерировать все перестановки в виде строк с разделителем:

```
with t as
 (select level n from dual connect by level <= 8)
select sys_connect_by_path(t.n, ' ') as path
  from t
--Только полные последовательности
 where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
--Рекурсия без повторений 
connect by nocycle t.n <> prior t.n
```

Результат потом можно разбить на 8 столбцов по необходимости.

Comment: Оооо, спасибо большое. Похожее пробовал, но отрабатывала еще дольше. CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 и nocycle всё меняют. Раньше не приходилось рекурсивными запросами пользоваться, не знаю возможностей (а там где читал такое не упоминалось).

Comment: Выполнение кстати гораздо дольше на фоне предыдущего варианта - 0.9с вместо 0.2с), но красиво :)

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов то, что вариант Zergatul быстрее неудивительно, иерархические запросы усложняют запрос. По псевдостолбцам вроде хорошо в документации написано: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332

Answer (score 3):

Проверял в MSSQL, но думаю принципиально различий не будет. Меньше секунды:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(nv INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl(nv)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)

SELECT t1.nv, t2.nv, t3.nv, t4.nv, t5.nv, t6.nv, t7.nv, t8.nv
FROM
    @tbl t1
    INNER JOIN @tbl t2 ON t2.nv != t1.nv
    INNER JOIN @tbl t3 ON t3.nv != t2.nv AND t3.nv != t1.nv
    INNER JOIN @tbl t4 ON t4.nv != t3.nv AND t4.nv != t2.nv AND t4.nv != t1.nv
    INNER JOIN @tbl t5 ON t5.nv != t4.nv AND t5.nv != t3.nv AND t5.nv != t2.nv AND t5.nv != t1.nv
    INNER JOIN @tbl t6 ON t6.nv != t5.nv AND t6.nv != t4.nv AND t6.nv != t3.nv AND t6.nv != t2.nv AND t6.nv != t1.nv
    INNER JOIN @tbl t7 ON t7.nv != t6.nv AND t7.nv != t5.nv AND t7.nv != t4.nv AND t7.nv != t3.nv AND t7.nv != t2.nv AND t7.nv != t1.nv
    INNER JOIN @tbl t8 ON t8.nv != t7.nv AND t8.nv != t6.nv AND t8.nv != t5.nv AND t8.nv != t4.nv AND t8.nv != t3.nv AND t8.nv != t2.nv AND t8.nv != t1.nv
```

Принципиальное различие в том, что ваш запрос перебирает `8^8=16777216` вариантов, а мой уже на первых join-ах отсекает большую их часть.

Comment: Да, работает быстро (малость переделал под свой формат). 0.2 секунды. Хотя выглядит как-то по-индийски :) Ни тебе рекурсий, ничего такого. Если размерность задачи изменится, то нужно переписывать алгоритм (ну или динамически формировать). Но, конечно, лучше, чем то что я "в лоб" написал :3

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов спора нет, выглядит по-индийски, зато быстро работает :) Посмотрим, предложат ли лучше варианты