# Как прокинуть значения рекурсивной функции наверх?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Нужна функция, которая возвращает все перестановки чисел. Нашел в интернетах в виде процедуры:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_exercise AS

    PROCEDURE pipe_all_chessmates_placements(pre in varchar2 default null, str in varchar2 default '12345678');

END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_exercise AS

  PROCEDURE pipe_all_chessmates_placements(pre in varchar2, str in varchar2) IS
    prefix varchar2(30);
    stringg varchar2(30);
    strlen number;
  begin
    strlen := length(str);
    if NVL(strlen, 0) = 0 then
       dbms_output.put_line(pre);
    else
      for i in 1..strlen loop
        prefix := pre || SUBSTR(str,i,1);
        stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i - 1) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
        pipe_all_chessmates_placements(prefix,stringg);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end pipe_all_chessmates_placements;

END;
/
begin
  test_exercise.pipe_all_chessmates_placements();
end;
```

То есть в таком виде он выведет все перестановки. Но что если я хочу вместо процедуры использовать функцию? В таком случае процедура должна что-то возвращать. Однако тогда возврат происходит в двух местах (там где в текущем коде dbms_output.put_line и там, где происходит рекурсивный вызов процедуры). Пробовал вместо вывода добавить PIPE ROW, но тогда нельзя вернуть результат всей функции в месте рекурсивного вызова т.к. воспринимает функцию как конвеерную (то есть, не сработает return pipe_all_chessmates_placements(prefix,stringg);). А результат перестановки я хочу использовать в дальнейших запросах, поэтому нельзя просто вывести в консоль. Как правильнее будет изменить процедуру в функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что ж, похоже, вопрос не заинтриговал сообщество, запосчу свой вариант. Но он плохой. Потому что выполняется 11 секунд (на SQL с помощью комьюнити аналогичный функционал получилось выстроить за 0.2 и 0.9 секунд).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_exercise AS

    type permutations_table is table of varchar2(8);    
    function pipe_all_chessmates_placements(pre in varchar2 default null, str in varchar2 default '12345678')
      return permutations_table
      pipelined;

END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_exercise AS

  function pipe_all_chessmates_placements(pre in varchar2, str in varchar2) return permutations_table pipelined IS
    prefix varchar2(30);
    stringg varchar2(30);
    strlen number;
  begin
    strlen := length(str);
    if NVL(strlen, 0) = 0 then
       pipe row (pre);
    else      
      for i in 1..strlen loop
        prefix := pre || SUBSTR(str,i,1);
        stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i - 1) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
        for j in (select * from pipe_all_chessmates_placements(prefix,stringg)) loop
          pipe row (j.column_value);
        end loop;
      end loop;
    end if;
  end pipe_all_chessmates_placements;

END;
/
select count(*) from test_exercise.pipe_all_chessmates_placements();
```

Comment: А вариантом на SQL не поделитесь?

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Конечно, вчера выносил на обсуждение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937813/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-sql-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5

Comment: а что вы за задачу решаете?

Comment: @Yaroslav все возможные расстановки ладей на доске. Сводится к комбинаторной задаче на перебор комбинаций чисел от 1 до 8

Comment: что Вы итоге хотите получить, список вариантов или количество вариантов?

Comment: @Yaroslav вы искренне думаете, что я ради подсчёта факториала так изголиться решил? Количество там считается ради того чтобы оценить время выполнения.

Comment: мало ли) кстати производительность можно еще увеличить если добавить `PARALLEL_ENABLE`

Comment: @Yaroslav Хмммм. Добавил эту клаузу после pipelined - время работы не изменилось. Я точно правильно добавил? Звучит так-то полезно :)

Comment: Вы правильно все поняли `http://iais.kemsu.ru/odocs/ora/pipelined_table_funcs.html#parallel_enabled`